# VS 2017 Live Unit Testing persisted data directory is read only

Tags: visual-studio, live-unit-tests

I'm having an issue with live unit testing, and have found that the solution may be to set a different persisted data directory (seen below). I try to do this, but that field is read-only for me. Running VS as administrator does nothing. What could cause this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop Live Unit Testing in order to change the settings.

That's what worked for me.

Comment: Wow you'd think i'd have tried that already, but that fixed it, thanks! That project is shelved right now, but it's good info